# replace tab with space

Tags: json, jq

input json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "cust1",
    "grp": [
      {
        "id": "46",
        "name": "BA2"
      },
      {
        "id": "36",
        "name": "GA1"
      },
      {
        "id": "47",
        "name": "NA1"
      },
      {
        "id": "37",
        "name": "TR3"
      },
      {
        "id": "38",
        "name": "TS1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

how to get .grp[] names separated with space on @tsv output?

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.name, (.grp//[{"name":"-"}]|.[]|" ",.name)]|@tsv' test_inp
cust1           BA2             GA1             NA1             TR3             TS1
```

expected output for above sample:

```
cust[TAB]BA2[SPACE]GA1[SPACE]NA1[SPACE]TR3[SPACE]TS1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`jq`** approach:

```
jq -r '.[] | [.name, (.grp | map(.name) | join(" "))] | @tsv' input.json
```

The output:

```
cust1   BA2 GA1 NA1 TR3 TS1
```